# Python: Directed, labeled graph where nodes can be dragged by mouse

Tags: python, graph, plotly-dash, interactive

Trying to display a directed labeled graph where nodes can be dragged by mouse. [Dash/Cytoscape](https://dash.plotly.com/cytoscape), Plotly, matplotlib or any other Python lib will do. So far I have this [Dash/Cytoscape](https://dash.plotly.com/cytoscape) code:

```
import dash
import dash_cytoscape as cyto
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    cyto.Cytoscape(
        id='cytoscape',
        layout={'name': 'grid'},
        style={'width': '100%', 'height': '400px'},
        elements=[
            {'data': {'id': 'A' }},
            {'data': {'id': 'B' }},
            {'data': {'id': 'C' }},
            {'data': {'id': 'AB', 'source': 'A', 'target': 'B'}, 'classes': 'arrow'},
            {'data': {'id': 'BC', 'source': 'B', 'target': 'C'}, 'classes': 'arrow'}
        ],
        stylesheet=[
            {'selector': 'node', 'style': {'background-color': 'lightblue', 
                                           'label': 'data(id)', 'text-valign': 
                                           'center', 'text-halign': 'center'}},
            {'selector': 'edge', 'style': {'curve-style': 'bezier', 
                                           'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle', 
                                           'line-color': 'gray', 'target-arrow-color': 'gray'}}
        ],
        userZoomingEnabled=False,
        userPanningEnabled=False
    ),

])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Dragging nodes works. Any idea how to change node labels A,B,C to a longer texts such as, for example:

```
A = '1: a long line'
B = '2: even longer text'
C = '3: once upon a time there lived ...'
```

Other Python frameworks to do the job?